# Stick passing through glass leaves a possibly parabolic hole

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am trying to understand what happens in this gif video:

[image]

Source: http://9gag.com/gag/aAVp4V9/is-this-even-possible

It is quite interesting because at a first look, it was very counter-intuitive.

Assuming that the yellow glass is the $xy-$plane, at first I thought that this is the projection map: $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2$. However, the projection of a line in $\mathbb R^3$ onto a plane must still be a line, but not a paralobic (or maybe hyperbolic or trigonometric) curve. So, this "thing" is not a projection, but something else.

What can be a function describing this situation? And what is the type (parabola, hyperbola, sine, circle etc.) of the curve on the glass?

Comment: The rotating line generates a hyperboloid which projects onto the xy plane in the form of a hyperbola. Maybe.

Comment: I believe the hole is (part of) a hyperbola. Specifically, the rotating rod is demonstrating the fact that a [hyperboloid of one sheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid) is a ["(doubly-)ruled surface"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_surface); that is to say, the curved hyperboloid surface is the union of a family of straight lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hyperboloid of one sheet is a doubly ruled surface; if it is a hyperboloid of revolution, it can also be obtained by ***revolving a line about a skew line***.

Source: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid)